# Mixed debugging (C#, C++) in VS Code via docker

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

We've recently moved our development from Visual Studio to VS Code. Our code solution contains .NET Core C# which hands calculations off to C++. In Visual Studio, we were able to seamlessly debug between C# and C++.

We initially moved to running the multi-project solution in a VM and using the [remote development features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) of VS Code. We use two Launch configurations:

```
{
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "${workspaceFolder}/src/build/Debug/Cpp/",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Run C#",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/AppProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/AppProject.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/AppProject",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "EnvironmentName": "Development",
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src/build/Release/Cpp/;$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
}
```

First running "Run C#" then running "(gdb) Attach" and selecting the `dotnet` process to attach to. This worked, allowing us to step down from C# into C++.

We've now moved to a Docker set up, where the source is mounted into a container with the build tools built in ([as described in the VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)). This is roughly our `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "image": [custom image in a private code repository],
    "forwardPorts": [various ports to serve web interfaces],
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined"
    ],
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.cpptools",
        "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
        "hbenl.vscode-test-explorer",
        "derivitec-ltd.cmake-test-adapter",
        "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
        "fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer",
        "derivitec-ltd.vscode-dotnet-adapter"
      ],
      "mounts": [
          "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.gitconfig,target=/root/.gitconfig,type=bind,consistency=cached",
          "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,type=bind,consistency=cached"
      ]
  }
```

In this set up, we've been able to successfully debug C# and C++ code separately, but the above flow of running the C# project and attaching GDB after it does not work as expected. The C# process exits, while the "(gdb) Attach" call starts multiple processes which run into various exceptions at launch. I've pasted the [full output to Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Y94BC6LX).

Much of the advice I've found is confused due to:

- legacy methods such as calling docker directly ([omnisharp/omnisharp-vscode issue on debugging in docker](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1369))
- alternative setups where source code is packaged into a docker container rather than mounted ([VS Code docs for debugging .NET Core in docker](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-netcore))
- alternative setups where build tools live in a docker container but VS Code communicates with the docker container via SSH rather than using the dev container approach recommended in the docs ([Microsoft blog post on developing C++ with VS Code and docker](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-vs-code-for-c-development-with-containers/))
- C++ seemingly having special requirements for debugging, especially where docker is concerned

  - The `runArgs` description in the [devcontainer.json reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_devcontainerjson-reference):

    > For example, "runArgs": [ "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined" ] allows ptrace based debuggers like C++ to work in the container.
- VS Code docs suggesting that debugging should work exactly as it does natively when using remote development tools (["Debugging in a container" from VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_debugging-in-a-container))

How should I debug both C# and C++ running within a docker container using VS Code?

Comment: Same request here..